# React Nested Routes with layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

We are writing a react highly scalable application and having a requirement for the nested level of routings.

```
<Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired}>
        <SecureRoute path="/:path?" exact>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateLayout>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/ml" exact component={MachineLearning} />
                <Route path="/ml/dataSources" exact component={DataSources}></Route>                
                <Route path="/ml/settings" exact component={MLSettings}></Route>
                <Route path="*" exact component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </PrivateLayout>
          </Switch>
        </SecureRoute>
        <Route path="/login" render={() => <LoggedInRedirect />} />
        <Route path="/login/callback" component={LoginCallback} />
      </Security>
```

When I try to go to the "/ml/dataSources" OR "/ml/settings" I do get the blank page.

Comment: Did you try without exact. I mean you should write exact with initial route only

Comment: without exact nothing works :-(

Comment: Why you are using these route for open and close tag. Any special thibg which i am missing